# iOS SDK - How does one make a "fire and forget" web call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I have a web service that I want to send some information but I don't care about the response from that server. I just want to give the server the information and it does whatever it wants with it.

How could I do that in iOS with objective-C? I'm using at the moment a background thread web call but it gets a response which I'm worried that if the user closes the app or navigates between scenes, that the response coming back may crash the app with a null reference.

Comment: I don't think it would cause any problem if you don't handle the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have an **HTTP** web service. In the usual HTTP there's almost no such thing as "fire and forget". The closest thing is to send a HEAD request, because the convention about it is that a response to a HEAD method should not have a body. But it is still just a convention.

If you control the web service yourself, and for example, you are using a POST which returns an empty response, then due to HTTP logic you still have to:

1. establish a TCP/TLS connection (for https)
2. send an HTTP request
3. receive an HTTP response with 200 OK status

Each of these can fail, and if it does, you can't be sure that your call has reached the server. For example your server might return 500 Server Error, and it is up to you if you want to ignore it or not, but you have to wait for it. If you don't receive it, it might just time out (for example if you have sent a request and there is not response for a long time). Also note that sending the app to background and resource pressure might be another reason why the request is not delivered.

In many cases when you want to be sure that your request is delivered, then you have to inspect the response code, and probably retry your request a few times.

If you truly don't care that your request was delivered, you could just ignore NSURLResponse and NSError inside the completionHandler for your NSURLSessionDataTask.

Answer (score -1):

If you're really worried about this, and truly don't care about whether the request succeeds or fails, you could put wrap the request in a `try` block, then background it to another thread. That should completely insulate it from the rest of your app.